# transparent modal header bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a bootstrap modal and I want to set the header's background color to transparent, it did work with other colors but with transparent my header's color turn black.
My CSS:

```css
<style>
  .modal-header {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
</style>
```

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...abd,ajkwbldkajgwldkahgwldkjalwkjdhalkjwdhlakjwhdawdw
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/spuft/pen/KKzZvBa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the parent element `.modal-content` has a `background-color` of `#161415` (which is close to black like what you described).

Since your header is transparent, it will not have a background-color on its own but the parent has a background-color so that's what you are going to see - giving the illusion that the header has a black background color.

An analogy of this in the real world is if you place a transparent sheet of plastic at the top of a black notebook. You will still see black visually despite the plastic being at the top.

So to solve this, give your `.modal-content` transparent as well. Since they are transparent, the modal's overlay will be the dominant color visually.

```
.modal-content {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
}
```